# nodejs: nedb filename path causing problems; how to fix?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, nedb

I'm an experienced programmer, but relatively new to nodejs, nedb, Mocha.

nedb is a nodejs npm module for small data usages, that replicates some of the interface used in Mongodb.  I chose it because I'm building an app to run on a Beaglebone Black or Raspberry Pi and didn't want the overhead for Mongodb for my small data needs.

However, I'm having a problem with the path portion of the filename for nedb.  It works fine if the myapp.js I'm working on is invoked local to the current path, but if I invoke it from a different directory, like my Mocha test directory, then nedb won't work with the same path.  It won't work with relative path either; I have to specify the full path, starting with /home before I can get it to work from the Mocha test directory.  Needless to say, this is both inconvenient, and prohibitave for production, as it's not running with a base of /home in production.

In the code that follows, myapp.js is the application I'm developing and testing.  useMyapp.js is a utility test to use myapp.js for simplicity.  These are all in the same directory, and work properly when I invoke useMyapp.js.

myapp.js is located in /home/geek/project/public/javascripts/

Here is the code for myapp.js:

```
var Datastore = require("nedb");
var db = new Datastore({filename: "./calEvents.db", autoload: true});

function Myapp(year, month) {
    console.log('myapp: year: ' + year + ', month: ' + month);
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
}

Myapp.prototype.getAllData = function() {
    db.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('error: ', err);
        } else {
            console.log(" docs found: ", docs);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = Myapp;
```

useMyapp.js is located in the same directory at /home/geek/project/public/javascripts/

Here is the code for useMyapp.js, which works correctly, outputing the expected nedb records.

```
var Myapp = require("./myapp");

var myapp = new Myapp(2016, "Mar");

myapp.getAllData();
```

I copied useMyapp.js to my Mocha test directory, renamed it to be TestUseMyapp.js, into /home/geek/project/test/
I adjusted the require statment for relative path to myapp.js
Here's the contents of TestUseMyapp.js in /home/geek/project/test/

```
var Myapp = require("../public/javascripts/myapp");

var myapp = new Myapp(2016, "Mar");

myapp.getAllData();
```

The output from running this via nodejs is an empty data set:
    docs found: []

THE PROBLEM:
TestUseMyapp.js is able to find and load myapp.js per the 'require' statement, but the filename parameter for nedb is not working when myapp.js is invoked from a different directory.  This is causing me problems between development, Mocha testing, and running in production, as the file path are all different.

I created a duplicate of myapp.js, named it myapp2.js, and kept it in the same directory as myapp.js at /home/geek/project/public/javascripts.  In this, I changed the path for the nedb filename parameter.
Here's the code in myapp2.js PLEASE NOTE THE ONLY CHANGE IS TO THE filename PARAMATER PATH:

```
var Datastore = require("nedb");
var db = new Datastore({filename: "/home/geek/project/public/javascripts/calEvents.db", autoload: true});

function Myapp(year, month) {
    console.log('myapp: year: ' + year + ', month: ' + month);
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
}

Myapp.prototype.getAllData = function() {
    db.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('error: ', err);
        } else {
            console.log(" docs found: ", docs);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = Myapp;
```

This works as expected when I invoked the test against myapp2.js with the full path.

THE QUESTION:
How do I resolve the filename path issue with nedb so that I don't have to change it between development, Mocha testing, and deployment to production?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by inserting __dirname as part of the filename parameter.